# XSL transformation: utf-8 and iso-8859-1 compatibility

Tags: c#, xslt, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I use .NET class XslCompiledTransform for xslt transformation and I have a problem with encodings. I have this word **Förstelärare** in my input xml. Here is cases:

1. input xml file has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` - xslt file has `<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" ...` - **OK**
2. input xml file has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` - xslt file has `<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" ...` - **OK**
3. input xml file has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` - xslt file has `<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" ...` - **OK**
4. input xml file has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` - xslt file has `<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" ...` - **CORRUPTED** - I see **FÃ¶rstelÃ¤rare** in output xml.

input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<test>Förstelärare</test>
```

trans.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/test" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <test><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# code:

```
var xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\trans.xslt", new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore, XmlResolver = null }))
{
    xslCompiledTransform.Load(xmlReader);
}
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\input.xml", new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore, XmlResolver = null }))
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\output.xml", xslCompiledTransform.OutputSettings))
{
    xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);
}
```

output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>FÃ¶rstelÃ¤rare</test>
```

Why does it happen? It looks like I need to use `iso-8859-1` in my xslt file to prevent corruption cause it works in both cases `iso-8859-1` and `utf-8`.

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code and .NET code to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Code and xml are added.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in a .NET 4.6 console application, using VS 2012, the result document looks fine: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>Förstelärare</test>`. Are you sure the input file is correctly ISO-8859-1 encoded when you get the garbled non-ASCII characters?

Comment: How did you create input file?

Comment: I copied the sample you have shown into VS studio and saved it with the encoding of the editor pane set to "Western European (ISO)" in VS.

Answer (score 1):

The output you're seeing is the result of interpreting a string encoded with UTF-8 as if it were iso-8859-1.

There are two possibilities:

- Your source file is actually encoded as UTF-8: just because the XML declaration says iso-8859-1, that doesn't necessarily mean that's how the text has been saved. (EDIT: Based on comments, I believe this is what's happening in your case.)
- Alternatively, when you're writing it out as UTF-8 it's working just fine, but whatever you're using to inspect the output is ignoring that and assuming it's iso-8859-1.

Here's the character in it's various encodings:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm

I would suggest looking at your source document in a hex editor, and immediately following the 'F' (70 or 0x46 in any encoding), you should see 0xF6 if it's in iso-8859-1 as per the XML declaration- in which case you're probably reading the output in the wrong encoding. If it's 0xC3 0xB6, that's UTF-8, and the encoding in the XML declaration of your source is wrong.

Comment: After '0x46' I see '0xc3 0xb6'. Looks like it's utf-8. Here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file I see: "for example, a file with the first three bytes 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF is probably a UTF-8 encoded file. However, it might be an ISO-8859-1 file which happens to start with the characters ï»¿". It's my case. I see ï»¿ at the begining of input file.

Comment: No, that's the UTF-8 byte order mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark. Definitely a UTF-8 source file. This means your fix is to change the encoding in your source to UTF-8; from your question, this appears to work in either case.

Comment: Just to clarify; while it's generally possible (although highly unlikely) that an iso-8859-1 encoded file might begin with those three characters, that's certainly not true of an XML document, or it wouldn't be valid XML. The first byte in the payload of an XML document MUST be `<` (0x3c), whether that begins a comment, xml declaration, processing instruction or of course the root element. For those three bytes to appear before it, it MUST be a byte order mark.